# TensorFlow strange (random?) output expected for RegisterGradient

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have created a custom op using the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op), and modified it a bit. I want to use this op as input for the `compute_gradients` method.

My op expects three inputs: target values, predicted values, and another matrix. It returns a new matrix with the same shape as the target values.

However, when I use @ops.RegisterGradient for this method, it expects strange return values, giving this message in one script:

```
ValueError: Num gradients 1 generated for op name: "SoftDtwJacobianSqEuc"
op: "SoftDtwJacobianSqEuc"
input: "targets"
input: "mul"
input: "strided_slice"
 do not match num inputs 3
```

And this in another script:

```
ValueError: Num gradients 1 generated for op name: "SoftDtwJacobianSqEuc"
op: "SoftDtwJacobianSqEuc"
input: "decoder_targets"
input: "Reshape"
input: "strided_slice_8"
 do not match num inputs 3
```

A snippet of the code I am running (full example below):

```
# Calling the op
backwards = soft_dtw_jacobian_sq_euc_module.soft_dtw_jacobian_sq_euc(decoder_targets, decoder_predictions, alignment_matrix[1:-1,1:-1])

# Need to register, other wise get error: No gradient defined for operation...
@ops.RegisterGradient("SoftDtwJacobianSqEuc")
def _soft_dtw_jacobian_sq_euc_grad(op, grad):
    # To generate the error which mentions the expected return values:
    return(None)

    # This kind of works in the first script, as I can 'mul'tiply the gradient with the output of the op
    #return(None, soft_dtw_jacobian_sq_euc_module.soft_dtw_jacobian_sq_euc(decoder_targets, decoder_predictions, alignment_matrix[1:-1,1:-1]), None)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.02)
params = tf.trainable_variables() 
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(backwards, params)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(gradients)
```

Why is RegisterGradients expecting different return values? How does RegisterGradients determine these?

Preferably I would just return the output of the op (since that's what I made it for), but if I do not use RegisterGradient I get a "*No gradient defined for operation...*" error.

I have a complete working example here: [python part](https://pastebin.com/zNYsdHCP) and [c++ op](https://pastebin.com/WHvcy0qQ)

Using TensorFlow 1.2.1 and python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error before. The error message was generated in tensorflow function `gradients_impl.py`.

```
def _VerifyGeneratedGradients(grads, op):
  """Verify that gradients are valid in number and type.

  Args:
    grads: List of generated gradients.
    op: Operation for which the gradients where generated.

  Raises:
    ValueError: if sizes of gradients and inputs don't match.
    TypeError: if type of any gradient is not valid for its input.
  """
  if len(grads) != len(op.inputs):
    raise ValueError("Num gradients %d generated for op %s do not match num "
                     "inputs %d" % (len(grads), op.node_def, len(op.inputs)))
```

Now we can see this error means for your op `SoftDtwJacobianSqEuc` , you gave it three inputs. **TensorFlow expects you to give three output for the function that generates gradients `_soft_dtw_jacobian_sq_euc_grad`, each output w.r.t each input for the function for forward propagation.**

Note that actually you only want the gradients for the first input, and the other two gradients will not be used anymore in the back propagation, you can just return two more `fake_gradients` with the right shape.

Although my answer seems to be a little bit late, still hope it helps!